# Eclipse not pasting copied text (Java/Mac)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, copy-paste

I am having this weird problem where when I select text (Cmd-C) and then try to copy it to another location (Cmd-V) it behaves as though it wants to copy the file as if I had the file name selected instead of the text.  Trying to paste in a text window pastes the file itself, so it's clear the copy is what is at fault.  Trying the menu option to copy (Edit->copy) does the same thing, so it's not a key interpretation issue.

This started happening to me after I had closed eclipse and then re-opened it later.  No settings had been changed.  A related issue that cropped up that might help identify is that eclipse stopped showing the file/line that the stack trace was on in debug mode (break points work, just doesn't pick up the file/line #).  If you right-click on the stack trace item and tell it to go to the source code - it does, and appears to look correct, it just doesn't do it automatically when you hit the breakpoint.  Both issues started happening after the restart.

Both are equally disturbing - but this post is primarily about the pasting issue.

Comment: This is good way to not use copy&paste programming :)

Answer (score 3):

The debug trace issue happens to me too. I close Eclipse, then delete the ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core" folder in the associated Workspace, then restart. This clears the cache.

Comment: The path should be  ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core"